# Autocorrelation and frequency of occurence

Tags: auto-correlation

Recently, I started reading Zuckerman's biography of Jim Simons - "The Man Who Solved the Market". There is an interesting para on page 110 - "When you flip a coin, you have a 25% chance of getting heads twice in a row, but there in correlation b/w one flip to the next. By contrast,Straus, Laufer and Berlekamp determine that the correlation of price moves in deutche marks b/w any two consecutive time periods was as much as 20%, meaning that the sequence repeated more than half the time"  - 
This last line is throwing me off....I've always used autocorrelation, or correlation as is done in traditional statistics courses; just the degree of association b/w two data series at a point in time, or over time etc. I've never associated either of the two metrics to a frequency of an event occurring. I've no idea how the author connects the 20% autocorrelation to the event occurring more than half the time....could anyone elaborate and point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had trouble with a similar concept and I managed to develop a proof that related probability of successive occurrence with autocorrelation. [Interpreting Autocorrelation as probability](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53351/interpreting-autocorrelation-as-probability). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check and get back :)